# Get CameraId from Camera object in android

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I am developing on Nexus 7 that only has a front-facing camera. Thus, most of the default camera-related retrievals fail as they try to return information for first back-facing camera. What I would like to know is whether it is possible to retrieve the camera ID from an already retrieved camera object?

Please, understand that I do not want to iterate over the list of cameras in order to match one to the current camera. Also, I did retrieve the camera using that method but didn't need to persist the ID of the camera.

In one of my classes, separate from camera acquisition class, I am trying to get a hold of the camcorder's profile. I invoke it with CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.HIGH_QUALITY); Documentation states that get(int quality):

> Returns the camcorder profile for the first back-facing camera on the device at the given quality level. If the device has no back-facing camera, this returns null.

Thus, I need a cameraId for the currently open (front-facing) camera.

Thanks for any help!